# XML::Parser dies on big file

Tags: xml, perl, openstreetmap

I'm using Perl script for extracting POLY from OSM files: https://github.com/sev-/osm/blob/master/getbound.pl

Recently I've got a problem with one big file (around 60M):

```
curl -XPOST "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter" -d"data=[timeout:900];(node(56.59,60.0,56.99,60.96);<);out;" > e.osm
perl getbound.pl -file e.osm 1104258 > e.poly
>unclosed token at line 173936, column 2, byte 9999947 at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/XML/Parser.pm line 187.
```

The XML file is well-formed, the mentioned lines looks fine, and the error message doesn't change at all when I delete the line. Looks like there is overflow in some byte counter inside the library.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Not 100% but what is the memory limit on loading into memory? wouldn't 60M be above the limit?

Comment: It'll take far far more than 60MB to load a 60MB file into memory, but I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Re "The XML file is well-formed", XML::Parser has a different opinion on the matter.

Comment: @ikegami xmlwf says it's well-formed

Comment: xmlwf uses expat, just like XML::Parser. So you've just told me that expat thinks the file is valid and that it thinks otherwise. One possibility is that you tested two different docs.

Comment: @ikegami other possibility is that something is wrong in XML::Parser installed on my macos 10.9, or in getbound.pl itself. I was checking the same file for sure. 

And it is puzzling indeed, why these two programs both using expat give me different output.

Comment: Re "other possibility is that something is wrong in XML::Parser installed on my macos 10.9", Not likely.

Comment: Re "other possibility is that something is wrong in getbound.pl itself", No, a bug in `getbound.pl` would not cause XML::Parser to incorrectly report that a valid XML document is invalid.

Comment: Have you determined what document you actually passed to XML::Parser (XML::Simple) yet?

Comment: I've updated post with reproduction steps

Comment: Did you take a look at line 173936? Does it look correct?

Comment: @scai yes, just like rest of the lines. I tried removing it, but error message remained the same, up to line and byte number.

Comment: `byte 9999947` does indeed look suspicious.

Comment: @ikegami If you mean "figure out what getbound.pl makes to original file before parsing it" then the answer is no. I didn't use Perl for last 10 years or more, so it's difficult for me to debug it.

Comment: What part do you have a problem with, opening a file or printing to one? (I'd use `binmode` on the handle.)

Comment: You'll find you only have the first 10,000,000 bytes of it.

Comment: I'm getting the same error: `unclosed token at line 173936, column 2, byte 9999947`. But the file does indeed look correct and `xmllint` doesn't report any error either (except for a missing DTD). So I guess there is a bug in the library.

Comment: @scai, No, it does not. You didn't pass the same thing to `xmllint` as you did to XML::Parser/XML::Simple. The file passed to XML::Parser/XML::Simple only has 10,000,000 bytes and it's suppose to have 6 times that many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
open my $file, '<', $filename;
read $file, $osmdata, 10_000_000;
```

with

```
open my $file, '<', $filename;
local $/;
$osmdata = <$file>;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the original `10_000_000` does? Is it a buffer size?

Comment: Interesting. Limiting the amount of bytes to read from a XML file looks like a strange idea.

Comment: @scai VERY strange indeed. This possibility just didn't get to my head.

Comment: @scai, I don't think the point was to limit; I think the programmer figured it was a simple way to slurp a file.